# How to stop printing error pages in ReportViewer using C#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have a master report file and a sub report file.

Master report file calls sub report file.

Let's have a look at the code first.

```
    private void CreatePDF(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            // Variables
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;
            string _strGijunMonth = DateTime.Parse(GijunMonth).ToString("yyyyMM");
            byte[] bytes = null;

            // Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MasterReport.rdlc";
            viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

            DataTable _dt = base.GetDataTable(
               "my_procedure"
               , _strMainNo
               );
            _intTotalPage = _dt.Rows.Count * 2;

            ReportDataSource _ds = new ReportDataSource();
            _ds.Value = _dt;
            _ds.Name = "SetData";
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(_ds);

            // sub report event
            viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);

            // print
            viewer.RefreshReport();
            bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

            System.IO.FileStream newFile1 = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            newFile1.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            newFile1.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string MAINT_NO = e.Parameters["MAINT_NO"].Values[0];
            string _strGijunMonth = DateTime.Parse(GijunMonth).ToString("yyyyMM");

            // get sub report procedure
            DataSet _dsCust_Info = base.GetDataSet(
                "my_sub_procedure"
                , MAINT_NO
                , _strGijunMonth
                );

            ----> by somehow, it should throw error. If so, I should not print error page to pdf.
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        }
    }
```

My application calls "CreatePDF" method with file name argument.

Let's say that I have to print to PDF 5 pages.

While calling LocalReport_SubreportProcessing event, some of sub reports have error value in data. So, I throw an error in LocalReport_SubreportProcessing event.

For example, when I say that there are 5 pages and only 1, 2, 3 and 5 pages are okay and the number 4 page should not be printed as PDF.

I wonder how I can delete PDF page which is already created by ReportViewer.
As you can see, LocalReport_SubreportProcessing event comes after creating PDF file.

Anyone has any idea to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe reportViewer.CancelRendering(0); 
when you detect an error?